# How to zoom in to a particular region of a video using Adobe Premiere Pro CC?

Tags: premiere, zoom

**Desired Behaviour**

Create an instructional video that 'zooms in' to parts of the video like in this video:

The first region I want to zoom into is the `top right` of the video.

**Environment**

Premiere Pro Version: 13.1.2 (build 9)
Video dimensions:  1920 wide x 1080 high

**Default `Video Effects` Settings**

Position: 960 , 540
*These values seem to represent the center of the video, ie half of the video's dimensions, the first value seems to be the horizontal axis position, the second value seems to be the vertical axis position.*
Scale: 100
Anchor Point:  960, 540

**What I've Tried**

I looked at a few tutorials for zooming, including the one mentioned above, and they all seem to say you need to:

1. Put your cursor where you want the zoom to start.
2. Go to `Effect Controls` panel and click `Position` and `Scale` icons so they turn into clocks.
3. Put your cursor where you want the zoom to end.
4. Adjust the `Scale` and `Position` values so that the desired area of the screen is shown.

My first attempt to zoom into the `top right` of the screen is 'kind of' working.

At the first keyframe, the values are:

Position:  960, 540
Scale: 100
Anchor Point:  960, 540

At the second keyframe, the values are:

Position:  -650, 1480
Scale: 268
Anchor Point:  960, 540

But I have two problems:

- I can't quite tell if i am zooming 'outside' the edges of the video, even by a few pixels.
- I can't see what the relationship between the new and old `Position` values is to make sure I am squarely in the top right corner of the screen.

I googled for things like `"how to keep zoom within constraints of the video"` and `"how to zoom into top right of video"` but that didn't yield anything helpful, so my terminology must be wrong.

**Questions**

1. What is the correct approach to zooming in to a particular region of the video?
2. Should I be using the `Anchor Point` setting as well as `Position` and `Scale`?